# Importing library in Dart on Windows

Tags: import, dart

I've been trying to make a library in Dart and import it in my project. Though for some reason it won't do it.

Here's how it looks:
[image: Bug]
It says it can't find the library, though the path is correct. I also tried a bunch of other paths:

- SmartCanvas.dart
- SmartCanvas/SmartCanvas.dart
- SmartCanvas
- SmartCanvas/SmartCanvas
- ./SmartCanvas/SmartCanvas.dart
- ../SmartCanvas/SmartCanvas.dart
- ./SmartCanvas.dart
- ../SmartCanvas.dart
- ./SmartCanvas
- ../SmartCanvas

Note: The project I'm trying to import this library into is located somewhere totally different on my harddrave (my dropbox folder.)

Anyone knows what I should use as path, or how I can import the library properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the troubles here. We're working on a package manager to make this a lot easier.

Comment: @SethLadd Awesomeness, that's great to hear :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for windows

```
#import('/c:/users/pablo/pablo\'s documents/projects/smartcanvas/smartcanvas.dart');
```

Answer (score 3):

`#import` expects a full path or correct relative path to a .dart file that has the `#library` line.

Here is an example from working code:

https://github.com/johnmccutchan/DartVectorMath/blob/master/test/console_test_harness.dart

At the top you see `#import('../lib/vector_math_console.dart');`

which is located:

https://github.com/johnmccutchan/DartVectorMath/blob/master/lib/vector_math_console.dart

Chopping off the github url prefix, we are left with:

```
test/console_test_harness.dart
lib/vector_math_console.dart
```

The import line uses the correct relative path from test/ into ../lib/ to find vector_math_console.dart (the library).

HTH,
John

Comment: In the screenshot I use the full path: @"C:\Users\Pablo\Pablo's Documents\Projects\SmartCanvas\SmartCanvas.dart" though that doesn't work either. Why doesn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

To import local libraries in dart, I'd recommend using the the path dependency in the pubspec.yaml.  This is a much cleaner approach then embedding absolute paths in the dart code.

Read about it here: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html#path-packages